# Google Online Account setup not working on fresh install Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, google

I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 (april 26, 2016) and, when i'm going to setup a google online account, the process doesn't work. It stop in the step 3, with a blank screen. I guess there is a problem with the new sign in page of Google. The images below shows the process (the black marks are for hide my email).

[image: Password window]

[image: Blank screen after password]

Is someone doing the same thing to you? Does anybody know what is it due to?

Comment: don't know, but have the same problem, i noticed it after update to 17.04. This worked ok before. Maybe google changed something. btw. i have 2FA enabled on my google account

Comment: same happens with an app password which shouldn't require the 2FA part

Comment: Today the same problem is still being presented on fresh installation of Fedora 25. It seems that the problem is by the goa authentication function that uses Gnome (for example, with Thunderbird there is the same problem, and It uses the same functionality). On fresh install of Linux Mint 18 KDE the login with app password on Kmai is working good.

Comment: By the way, to my surprise, after a long time of not using KDE, the Plasma 5.8 LTS version in Linux Mint 18 works wonderfully. I have made the decision to change my distribution (and desktop) for Linux Mint 18 KDE (where the problem with Google account authentication does not occur).

Comment: Fresh install, in addition to another desktop install, neither of which work.  I was reading online where this was a known bug in (libgtk?) libraries but I've got the latest (as of yesterday) versions installed and I'm still seeing the blank screen as described above.

Comment: This: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkit2gtk/+bug/1687019

Comment: Ok @MichealShallop, the problem was with webkit2gtk, the fix can be found in this post: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkit2gtk/+bug/1687019 comment # 31

Comment: @JoseRendon - thanks!  I downloaded and installed the fix on both my 16.04 nodes and it's working great.